# How to format strings with indentation based on an integer?

Tags: rust, string-formatting

Is there a better way to print/format string indentation besides doing:

```
let text_to_indent = "Indented text!";
for i in 0..indent {
    print!(" ");
}
println!("{}", text_to_indent);
```

Does Rust have a more convenient way to do this?

Comment: For reference [the formatting syntax](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/#syntax).

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
println!("{:indent$}Indented text!", "", indent=indent);
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=49478456d7a0950bce4153f378175d7b&version=stable&backtrace=0))

The first placeholder does the indentation. It will print the argument 0 (empty string, `""`) with a padding (with spaces) as specified in argument `ident`.

Printing a variable can be done like this:

```
println!("{:indent$}{}", "", text_to_indent, indent=level);
```

Comment: Ah nice! I looked at the minimum `width` parameter in the formatting syntax but didn't think about using this in conjunction with an empty string.

Comment: @MatthieuM. it's kinda hacky and I don't really like it... but it works ^_^

Comment: Another answer given on IRC: `format!("{}{}", format_args!("{: >1$}", "", 4), "*indented* text")`

Comment: I can't get this to work (using 1.21 / nightly) even though it works in the linked playground. Can't figure out why! Any ideas

Comment: @AndrewMackenzie What's the error? And what nightly exactly? I tried it using `1.23.0-nightly (45594d5de 2017-11-22)`, stable `1.22.1` and stable `1.21.0` -> all of those work. Maybe some typo or another error on your side?

Comment: doesn't seem to work for me either, eventhough it works in the playground o_O it just prints without indentation

Comment: In `rustc` 1.66 you don't need the `ident=ident` as the Rust devs have added capturing variables in `format!` strings.  [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=caf7cd6c323851f2e9c9be039329597e).